# SDL for a edit text box

Tags: c++, user-interface, cross-platform, sdl

I want to write a code editor which supports code highlighting, selection, search and replace and similar features.

Since I'm unsatisfied with normal edit box controls (I want WAY more flexibility) I decided to write my own UI controls. It would be great if the editor could run on linux and windows (I don't have a Mac but that would be great as well) and thus I've been thinking on using SDL to render the edit text box control.

As far as I know I can [draw anti-aliased text](http://www.sdltutorials.com/sdl-ttf) and SDL is nicely cross-compatible, but I'm unsure if functionalities like smooth scrolling could be implemented.

Question: **is it possible to use SDL for a custom edit text box and have smooth scrolling?**

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is LazyFoo's tutorial on editable text input boxes: http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/32_text_input_and_clipboard_handling/index.php

It doesn't do scrolling:  you'll have to do it yourself.  The LazyFoo tutorials on scrolling and scrolling backgrounds here ( http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/index.php ) should help, although it's not, obviously, a text box that's being scrolled.

Comment: http://lazyfoo.net/ has probably the most comprehensive set of tutorials for SDL out there at the moment